# When using nodes net library how does the socket pool work

Tags: node.js, sockets

I'm fairly new to programming with sockets, I've done some searching on the web but I can't find anything definitive to my question.

I know node is extremely fast at handling I/O tasks, but I was wondering how the net package works under the hood, in my example I have this code (its stripped for readability)

```
const net = require('net')

const server = net.createServer(function(socket) {
   socket.name = socket.remoteAddress + ":" socket.remotePort;
}).listen(127.0.0.1, 5000)
```

I want to be as clear as I can when I ask this, but whenever a socket is opened on the server, does node spawn its own new socket to serve that client, or is there one unified server that serves all connected clients?

For clarity (with a diagram) does the server look like this:

```
         S  
         |
  ---------------
  |      |      |
  C      C      C
```

Or this:

```
  S      S      S
  |      |      |
  C      C      C
```

The reason I ask, is I'm writing an application that interfaces with around 100 different hardware devices via TCP, I need to query the device on its status/serial number and other information.  The second model conceptually looks more correct in my head as I'd be sending a query to the hardware and then I'd get an event fire back on that socket on the server, to which I could perform any necessary updates.

I apologise if this question isn't worded too clearly, I didn't really know how else to express my query.  Any comments would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`net.createServer()` creates one server socket (listening on port 5000). There are many client sockets (one for each connection to the server socket). So I would say the first diagram is more correct. This is pretty much how all TCP servers operate.

Sending and receiving data on each client socket is not a problem. Just read from and write to the socket just like you normally would inside your connection handler.

Also, "socket pool" is not the correct term here as there is no pool (like you might have with database connections for example).

Comment: Thanks for the reply that clears a lot up for me.  The only thing thats confusing to me (if I consider Diagram 1) is how is concurrency managed?  Say 4 sockets are having a R/W that needs doing, do they all get queued or does the R/W happen concurrently, if so - how?

Comment: @macdex is correct; the majority of socket handling and multi-threaded applications is done using signals from parents to their children as described in your first diagram.

Comment: @jas- great thanks for the clarification...I don't normally ask more obscure questions like this on SO, but its been eating away at me today at work :)

Comment: @Alex network I/O happens on the main thread in node, but when data gets written out kind of depends. If you write a bunch of data at once, it's possible that some of it gets buffered in memory if the OS cannot keep up, so there can be a queue in that sense. Typically though the data gets flushed out as soon as possible.

Comment: @mscdex gotcha, that makes total sense - thanks for your help